# @Inject Not Injecting Beans from Application Context

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have a java command line application which utilises Beans defined in the Application Context File. I'm able to Inject the Beans into the main class using the following `ApplicationContextLoader` class which is called from the main method:

```
public class ApplicationContextLoader {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public ConfigurableApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    protected void loadApplicationContext(String... configLocations) {
        applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(configLocations);
        applicationContext.registerShutdownHook();
    }

    protected void injectDependencies(Object main) {
        getApplicationContext().getBeanFactory().autowireBeanProperties(main, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_NO, false);
    }

    public void load(Object main, String... configLocations) {
        loadApplicationContext(configLocations);
        injectDependencies(main);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DataGeneratorTestRunner dataGeneratorTestRunner = new DataGeneratorTestRunner();
        dataGeneratorTestRunner.launchTests(args, APPLICATION_CONTEXT);
        System.exit(0);
} 

public void launchTests(String[] args, String applicationContext) throws IOException{
            acl  = new ApplicationContextLoader();      
            acl.load(this, applicationContext);     
}
```

However, when i try to use the `@Inject` annotation in other classes within in my Application (not the Main class), i get Null pointer exceptions.  Is there an alternative/easier way to allow me to use the `@Inject` annotation throughout my Application to reference any Bean's defined in my Application Context File without having to specify a class name or even use the above ApplicationContextLoader Class?

Application Context:

```
<bean id="currentState" class="com.company.integration.sim.State">
</bean>

    <bean id="customerSim" class="com.company.integration.sim.CustomerSim">
    </bean>
```

I'm referencing the Beans as follows which is null:

```
public class CustomerSim {

@Inject private State currentState;
.
.
.
```

Comment: Spring will inject into any class that is constructed by spring.  the "other classes" in your application must be beans in the application context in order for spring to handle dependancies.

Comment: The 'other classes' are defined as Beans in the Application Context File but are null when i try to reference them?

Comment: You will need to show how you are referencing the other classes.  Consider adding some code that shows 1. how you get a reference to some other class and 2. the Null reference.

Comment: Please show your context and an example of a class with `@Inject`.

Comment: Please check the import of your `@Inject` annotation - maybe you have Guice framework picked up by maven or something.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, had a look at the import and its using 'javax.inject.Inject'

Comment: Do you have `<context:annotation-config/>` or component scanning enabled in your Spring configuration file?

Comment: Hi Boris, yes i have <context:annotation-config /> defined in the Application Context, I'm not using component scanning.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor

```
 protected void injectDependencies(Object main) {
    AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bpp = new AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    bpp.setBeanFactory(getApplicationContext());
    bpp.processInjection(main);
  }
```

I am not  sure the method you are using is supposed to work at all. Also if you develop tests, consider using [Spring Test Context framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html) instead.